# Dependency Injection. Preparing for ASP.NET vNext

Tags: c#, asp.net, dependency-injection, ioc-container, asp.net-core

We are currently in the need to implement an IoC Container in C# because dependencies are growing significantly in the last weeks in our projects.

We are not going (for now at least) to use all the features an IoC have but Constructor Injection and (rarely) Property Injection.

I played a bit with the [default DI in ASP.NET vNext](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/webdev/archive/2014/06/17/dependency-injection-in-asp-net-vnext.aspx) and it's more than enough for us.

Question is, since vNext isn't still ready for production, I'm looking for a IoC container that will use 'the same language' aka the most similar one.

I failed to find that information on the net, and I don't have the experience or knowledge to evaluate them by myself.

Which container do you think will be best for a) beginners to ioc world, b) similar to vNext otb ioc.

Comment: @Steven sorry you are right. I should mentioned asp.net or c# in there. There it is.

Comment: Pretty much any DI container would do for Constructor and Property Injection, so it would be a matter of taking your pick; I think answers to this question are going to be largely opinion based. I personally use Castle Windsor, but you may prefer Ninject, StructureMap, Autofac, Unity, Funq, Munq, or one of the several others available!

Comment: Currently there are adapters for StructureMap, AutoFac, Ninject, Windsor, and Unity. Going with any of those should make it very easy to plug your existing registrations into the vNext built in DI.

Comment: @AndersNS that was what I was asking for. Thank you. Mind adding as an answer so I can accept it ?

Comment: I have been using Unity with .net mvc and I am quite happy with that. https://www.nuget.org/packages/Unity/

Comment: The DI libraries for .NET are really mature and Microsoft will not get that level of maturity within the coming years (just take a look at how long it takes for Entity Framework to get there and how Unity DI is lacking behind). There will be many important features missing from ASP.NET's built-in DI container such as being able to [verify an diagnose](https://simpleinjector.codeplex.com/wikipage?title=Diagnostics) the container's configuration, and working with generic types. If you're developing a serious business application using DI, please pick a decent DI library.

Comment: What ASP.NET is doing is implement a [Conforming Container](http://blog.ploeh.dk/2014/05/19/conforming-container/) (an anti-pattern) and Mark Seemann as strong arguments on why this is a bad idea what ASP.NET is doing. I agree with him on that.

Comment: @Steven interesting read. Thanks. Guess I'm going to put Unity and don't worry about vNext implementation for now. I was expecting much more from Microsoft.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Currently there are adapters for StructureMap, AutoFac, Ninject, Windsor, and Unity. Going with any of those should make it very easy to plug your existing registrations into the vNext built in DI.

Check out the repository for aspnet Dependency Injection https://github.com/aspnet/DependencyInjection/tree/dev/src